# Displaying oracle queries on a website

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a website from scratch and I'm new to php/html. But I want to know why I can't get my column names to display in my table that I'm displaying on my page. It's just a simple query to see if I'm doing it correctly. It displays and updates like it's supposed to but the column names.

```
 $stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT a.artist_name as artists, g.genre_name as genre
                                    FROM artists a, genre g 
                                    WHERE a.genre_id = g.genre_id');
        //prepare
        if (!$stid) {
            $e = oci_error($conn);
            trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
        }

        // logic
        $r = oci_execute($stid);
        if (!$r) {
            $e = oci_error($stid);
            trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
        }

        // fetch 
        echo "<table class='table table-striped'>\n";
        while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
            echo "<tr>\n";
            foreach ($row as $item) {
                echo "   <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
            }
            echo "</tr>\n";

        }
        echo "</table>\n";

        oci_free_statement($stid);
        oci_close($conn);
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the column names use the foreach loop like this:

```
foreach ($row as $col => $item) {
                echo "   <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
            }
```

Now the variable $col will contain the column name.

Comment: Hmmm that's making my table display itself again just side by side. Maybe I'll try to just hardcode my own column names myself. The end result would be the same for me.